# FBAESEncryption not working for for ios

Tags: ios, encryption, aes

I am using `FBAESEncryption` for encrypt and decrypt of data, but encrypted value is not matching with Android encrypted value. I am using Key and IV.

I also Tried `CryptLib` but the outpus is the same, it is not matching with Android encryption.

Please can Any one help me with some link or source code?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: below code is used by Android Guys

Comment: please check padding which android use For iOS use kCCOptionPKCS7Padding.  Use this function for encryption [FBEncryptorAES encryptBase64String:symmetricKey keyString:asdadsad]; Share some code